# How to send plain text as request body using okhttp in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp

I need to send a plain text as the request payload to my web app. But I can't make it to work with okhttp. I don't need complicated body builder that okhttp comes with such as FormBody.Builder() or MultipartBody.Builder(). I just need a simple text body attached to a POST http request header. Something like this:

```kotlin
val myBody = "my own body text that my server understands"
val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(myUrl)
            .post(myBody) //does not work.
            .build()
        okHttpClient.newCall(request)...
```

If okhttp can't do it, is there an alternative to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OkHttp.

You can find an example in recipes - [Posting a String](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-string-kt-java)

Something like this:

```
private val client = OkHttpClient()

  fun run() {
    val postBody = """
        |Releases
        |--------
        |
        | * _1.0_ May 6, 2013
        | * _1.1_ June 15, 2013
        | * _1.2_ August 11, 2013
        |""".trimMargin()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.github.com/markdown/raw")
        .post(postBody.toRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN))
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
      if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

      println(response.body!!.string())
    }
  }

  companion object {
    val MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN = "text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
  }
```